# Plotting star orbits

Tags: python, graph

I want to plot the orbits, selecting those with zmax_lo greater than 1.5, and I have been trying, but have not had a favorable response. This is the first exercise from: https://www.astropy.org/astropy-tutorials/rst-tutorials/gaia-galactic-orbits.html#using-gala-to-numerically-integrate-galactic-stellar-orbits

the first thing I wanted to do was get the stars with zmax_lo greater than 1.5 with a loop and
with an if but i'm wrong in something

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
"""
Created on Tue Dec 27 16:19:41 2021

@author: 146282
"""
# astropy imports
import astropy.coordinates as coord
from astropy.table import QTable
import astropy.units as u
from astroquery.gaia import Gaia
# Third-party imports
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import numpy as np
# gala imports
import gala.coordinates as gc
import gala.dynamics as gd
import gala.potential as gp
from gala.units import galactic
# Note: the following lines require an internet connection, so we have
# provided the results of this query as a FITS file included with the
# tutorials repository. If you have an internet connection, feel free
# to uncomment these lines to retrieve the data with `astroquery`:
# job = Gaia.launch_job(query_text)
# gaia_data = job.get_results()
# gaia_data.write('gaia_data.fits')
query_text = '''SELECT TOP 4096 ra, dec, parallax, pmra, pmdec, radial_velocity, 
phot_g_mean_mag, phot_bp_mean_mag, phot_rp_mean_mag FROM gaiadr2.gaia_source WHERE 
parallax_over_error > 10 AND parallax > 10 AND radial_velocity IS NOT null ORDER BY 
random_index '''
gaia_data = QTable.read('gaia_data.fits')
print(gaia_data[:4])
dist = coord.Distance(parallax=u.Quantity(gaia_data['parallax']))
print(dist.min(), dist.max()) 
c = coord.SkyCoord(ra=gaia_data['ra'],
               dec=gaia_data['dec'],
               distance=dist,
               pm_ra_cosdec=gaia_data['pmra'],
               pm_dec=gaia_data['pmdec'],
               radial_velocity=gaia_data['radial_velocity'])
c[:4]
c.galactic[:4]
coord.Galactocentric()
galcen = c.transform_to(coord.Galactocentric(z_sun=0*u.pc,
                                         galcen_distance=8.1*u.kpc))
galcen[:4]
plt.hist(galcen.z.value, bins=np.linspace(-110, 110, 32))  
plt.xlabel('$z$ [{0:latex_inline}]'.format(galcen.z.unit))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

ax.plot(galcen.v_x.value, galcen.v_y.value,
    marker='.', linestyle='none', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlim(-125, 125)
ax.set_ylim(200-125, 200+125)

ax.set_xlabel('$v_x$ [{0:latex_inline}]'.format(u.km/u.s))
ax.set_ylabel('$v_y$ [{0:latex_inline}]'.format(u.km/u.s))

M_G = gaia_data['phot_g_mean_mag'] - dist.distmod
BP_RP = gaia_data['phot_bp_mean_mag'] - gaia_data['phot_rp_mean_mag']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

ax.plot(BP_RP, M_G,
    marker='.', linestyle='none', alpha=0.3)

ax.set_xlim(0, 3)
ax.set_ylim(11, 1)

ax.set_xlabel('$G_{BP}-G_{RP}$')
ax.set_ylabel('$M_G$')
np.seterr(invalid="ignore")
hi_mass_mask = ((BP_RP > 0.5*u.mag) & (BP_RP < 0.7*u.mag) &
            (M_G > 2*u.mag) & (M_G < 3.75*u.mag) &
            (np.abs(galcen.v_y - 220*u.km/u.s) < 50*u.km/u.s))

lo_mass_mask = ((BP_RP > 2*u.mag) & (BP_RP < 2.4*u.mag) &
            (M_G > 8.2*u.mag) & (M_G < 9.7*u.mag) &
            (np.abs(galcen.v_y - 220*u.km/u.s) < 50*u.km/u.s))
hi_mass_color = 'tab:red'
lo_mass_color = 'tab:purple'
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

ax.plot(BP_RP, M_G,
    marker='.', linestyle='none', alpha=0.1)

for mask, color in zip([lo_mass_mask, hi_mass_mask],
                   [lo_mass_color, hi_mass_color]):
ax.plot(BP_RP[mask], M_G[mask],
        marker='.', linestyle='none',
        alpha=0.5, color=color)

ax.set_xlim(0, 3)
ax.set_ylim(11, 1)

ax.set_xlabel('$G_{BP}-G_{RP}$')
ax.set_ylabel('$M_G$')

milky_way = gp.MilkyWayPotential()
milky_way
different_disk_potential = gp.MilkyWayPotential(disk=dict(m=8e10*u.Msun))
different_disk_potential
H = gp.Hamiltonian(milky_way)
w0_hi = gd.PhaseSpacePosition(galcen[hi_mass_mask].cartesian)
w0_lo = gd.PhaseSpacePosition(galcen[lo_mass_mask].cartesian)
w0_hi.shape, w0_lo.shape
orbits_hi = H.integrate_orbit(w0_hi, dt=1*u.Myr,
                          t1=0*u.Myr, t2=500*u.Myr)

orbits_lo = H.integrate_orbit(w0_lo, dt=1*u.Myr,
                          t1=0*u.Myr, t2=500*u.Myr)
fig = orbits_hi[:, 0].plot(color=hi_mass_color)
_ = orbits_lo[:, 0].plot(axes=fig.axes, color=lo_mass_color)
fig = orbits_hi[:, 0].plot(['x', 'v_x'],
                       auto_aspect=False,
                       color=hi_mass_color)
fig = orbits_hi[:, 0].cylindrical.plot(['rho', 'z'],
                                   color=hi_mass_color,
                                   label='high mass')
_ = orbits_lo[:, 0].cylindrical.plot(['rho', 'z'], color=lo_mass_color,
                                 axes=fig.axes,
                                 label='low mass')

fig.axes[0].legend(loc='upper left')
fig.axes[0].set_ylim(-0.3, 0.3)

zmax_hi = orbits_hi.zmax(approximate=True)
zmax_lo = orbits_lo.zmax(approximate=True)
bins = np.linspace(0, 2, 50)

plt.hist(zmax_hi.value, bins=bins,
     alpha=0.4, density=True, label='high-mass',
     color=hi_mass_color)
plt.hist(zmax_lo.value, bins=bins,
     alpha=0.4, density=True, label='low-mass',
     color=lo_mass_color);

plt.legend(loc='best', fontsize=14)

plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel(r"$z_{\rm max}$" + " [{0:latex}]".format(zmax_hi.unit))
print(zmax_lo)
zmax_lo2 = []
for item,value in range (len(zmax_lo)):
    if value >=1.5:
        zmax_lo2.append(value)
print(zmax_lo2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`zmax_lo` is not a dictionary.  It is a numpy array.  You don't iterate it with `for item,value`.  You should just be able to use numpy's fancy indexing without using a loop at all:

```
zmax_lo2 = zmax_lo[zmax_lo >= 1.5]
```

The `zmax_lo >= 1.5` part returns a boolean array with True where the expression is true, False elsewhere.  By passing that as an index, that selects only those elements where the boolean array is True.